# Mercurial: How to pull out an old changeset as a separate codebase, do work, merge, and continue working on current?

Tags: mercurial

I have a large codebase that I have been working on for a while. It is not ready to push live, even experimentally. However, my client is requiring a minor change that I cannot fix without pushing my whole new update (which is not ready). I would like to do the following:

1. Take a stable changeset (I know which one) and create a codebase that I can then work from in Visual Studio.
2. Make the (very minor) update
3. Commit my change
4. Upload my change to the server
5. Merge/push my changes
6. Be able to go on working on my current project with that minor change included

I don't want to screw anything up though. Can anyone offer some advice on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

1. `hg clone` then `hg update <rev>` to the stable changeset
2. Edit the code as needed
3. `hg commit`
4. Upload this version (stable + patch) to the server
5. `hg push` to the server (your new patch)
6. At some point, do `hg pull` in your main development clone when you don't have any uncommitted changes, then do `hg rebase` to make Mercurial adjust your main development changesets to come after the patch we made above.  The history will then be as if the "hotfix" had been done before you started working on your new development.

Comment: how do i clone starting at changeset b6c336cda757? Pretend that I'm a veritable novice with mercurial :)

Comment: You don't.  You clone as normal first, then say `hg update b6c336cda757` to roll the local repo to that point.

Comment: ah ok. that makes sense. i will try that and get back to you.

Comment: @John: Why do you suggest using `rebase` instead of simply merging the patch into the devolpment branch?

Comment: do i clone to a different directory? if so, how do i specify which directory to clone to?

Comment: @Oben: there's more than one way to skin this cat.  I like the way I posted--if you have an alternative, feel free to post it.  @Jason: Yes.  `hg clone source-repo target-dir`.

Comment: @John: I don't think just because I would prefer a merge is worth an own answer. But you might add it to your's as an alternative (also because merging is more the *standard* way to handle situations like this).

Comment: @Jason: `rebase` is an extension you have to enable. You'll want to [read about it](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) before using it. It changes the changeset ids because it re-writes repository history, so it's a tool to be careful with. Since you're unfamiliar with it, you might want to consider `merge` instead, at least until you understand `rebase`.